# I need to get an array from the wordpress database

Tags: database, javascript, php, google-maps

I need to convert this code

```
//This creates an array from the database and allows us to use it later in the jquery
//CREATE SQL STATEMENT
$sql_locations = "SELECT * FROM tbllocations";

//EXECUTE SQL STATEMENT
$rs_locations = mysqli_query($vconnection, $sql_locations);
$rs_locations_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_locations);



foreach( $rs_locations as $rs_location ) {
  $markers[] = array(
      "{$rs_location['place']}, {$rs_location['city']}",
     $rs_location['long'],
      $rs_location['lat']
  );
}
```

to wordpress. I have created a custom post type that would save longitude and latitude inputs. Which database table would i need to look in to get these inputs and then run them through that for each loop?

Will this work?

D

Comment: Impossible to know without knowing how do you save the info. Please edit the question with the info.

Comment: All good, I got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are asking for? Use it after the code you posted to create posts in loop and use thier ids to update meta fields. Replace "post_type" with your custom post type.

```
foreach ($markers as $marker){
    $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
        "post_title" => "something",
        "post_type" => "your-type",
        "post_status" => "publish", //by default they are drafts
        // etc.
    ));
    update_post_meta($post_id, "latitude", $marker['lat']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, "longitude", $marker['long']);
}
```

After that you can get those fields by using [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: This is exactly what I did, slightly different but Got it in the end